# Filtering a Dataset by another Dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

The task I am trying to accomplish is essentially filtering one dataset by the entries in another dataset by entries in an "id" column. The data sets I am working with are quite large having 10 of thousands of entries and 30 or so variables. I have made toy datasets to help explain what I want to do.

The first dataset contains a list of entries and each entry has  their own unique accession number(this is the id).

```
Data1 = data.frame(accession_number = c('a','b','c','d','e','f'), values =c('1','3','4','2','3','12'))
>Data1
      accession_number values
1                a      1
2                b      3
3                c      4
4                d      2
5                e      3
6                f     12
```

I am only interested in the entries that have the accession number 'c', 'd', and 'e'. (In reality though my list is around 100 unique accession numbers). Next, I created a dataframe with the only the unique accession numbers and no other values.

```
>SubsetData1
  accession_number
1                c
2                d
3                e
```

The second data set, which i am looking to filter, contains multiple entries some which have the same accession number.

```
>Data2
   accession_number values  Intensity col4       col6
1                 a      1 -0.0251304    a -0.4816370
2                 a      2 -0.4308735    b -1.0335971
3                 c      3 -1.9001321    c  0.6416735
4                 c      4  0.1163934    d -0.4489048
5                 c      5  0.7586820    e  0.5408650
6                 b      6  0.4294415    f  0.6828412
7                 b      7 -0.8045201    g  0.6677730
8                 b      8 -0.9898947    h  0.3948412
9                 c      9 -0.6004642    i -0.3323932
10                c     10  1.1367578    j  0.9151915
11                c     11  0.7084980    k -0.3424039
12                c     12 -0.9618102    l  0.2386307
13                c     13  0.2693441    m -1.3861064
14                d     14  1.6059971    n  1.3801924
15                e     15  2.4166472    o -1.1806929
16                e     16 -0.7834619    p  0.1880451
17                e     17  1.3856535    q -0.7826357
18                f     18 -0.6660976    r  0.6159731
19                f     19  0.2089186    s -0.8222399
20                f     20 -1.5809582    t  1.5567113
21                f     21  0.3610700    u  0.3264431
22                f     22  1.2923324    v  0.9636267
```

What im looking to do is compare the subsetted list of the first data set(SubsetData1), with the second dataset (Data2) to create a  filtered dataset that only contains the entries that have the same accession numbers defined in the subsetted list. The filtered dataset should look something like this.

```
   accession_number values  Intensity col4       col6
9                 c      9 -0.6004642    i -0.3323932
10                c     10  1.1367578    j  0.9151915
11                c     11  0.7084980    k -0.3424039
12                c     12 -0.9618102    l  0.2386307
13                c     13  0.2693441    m -1.3861064
14                d     14  1.6059971    n  1.3801924
15                e     15  2.4166472    o -1.1806929
16                e     16 -0.7834619    p  0.1880451
17                e     17  1.3856535    q -0.7826357
```

I don't know if I need to start making loops in order to tackle this problem, or if there is a simple R command that would help me accomplish this task. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: So `Data1` doesn't matter at all here? I don't understand why row 3 of `Data2` isn't in the desired output since it has an accession_number of "c".

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't realize that, and that was totally a typo on my part. Sorry about that Mr.Flick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
WantedData=Data2[Data2$ccession_number %in% SubsetData1$accession_number, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `inner_join` of `dplyr` package.

```
dat = inter_join(Data2, SubsetData1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `subset` function is designed for basic subsetting:

```
subset(Data2,accession_number %in% SubsetData1$accession_number)
```

Alternately, here you could `merge`:

```
merge(Data2,SubsetData1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions seem fine, but I like the readability of `dplyr`, so here's a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
new_dataset <- Data2 %>%
    filter(accession_number %in% SubsetData1$accession_number)
```

Comment: If you are going to use dplyr then `semi_join()` might be a better choice than `filter()`